# Can't get simple encryption to work in Unity: "CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0"

Tags: unity-game-engine, encryption, save, aes

I'm making a game in Unity, and I'm trying to make the save file unreadable.
I'm completely new to encryption, so I looked up how to do this, but I can't get it to work.

I get the following exception when trying to decrypt:
*CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0*

**I'm using Aes, with hardcoded 24-bytes Key and 16-bytes IV**

Here's my loading code:

```
if (File.Exists(dataFilePath))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(dataFilePath)))
        {
            string dataToLoad;

            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = key;
                aes.IV = IV;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(reader.Read()))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            dataToLoad = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var gameData = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveData>(dataToLoad);
        }
    }
```

And here's the saving code:

```
using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            byte[] encrypted;
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(JsonUtility.ToJson(gameData));
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
            writer.Write(encrypted);
        }
```

Comment: You should use a `FileStream` instead of the `MemoryStream` when loading (the `BinaryReader` is then not necessary). Analogously when saving.